# Single database tool to access different database types?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, derby

I’d like a visual database tool that will allow me to access multiple database types from the same program. I’m looking for anything that supports Mysql, PostgreSQL, and Derby. Anything else it supports is a bonus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can get ODBC drivers for your databases (should be available from the DB vendor) you can use MS Access.  If you want something free, I recommend [SQuirrel SQL Client](http://www.squirrelsql.org/).  It's implemented in Java, so you need JDBC drivers (usually also available for free) for each DB that you use.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [DbVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/index.html#EA). It could help with reverse engineering and creating fancy diagrams. It works with everything you could get drivers for but your database are natively supported.

Vision for Enterprise Architects could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know very few who support Derby but they support MySQL, PostgreSQL, Firebird and others...

Check this :

- [SQL maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/)
- [SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/)
- [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com) (not for PostgreSQL)
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AquaFold](http://www.aquafold.com/)'s Datastudio. It's written in Java, so it can access any DB that has a JDBC driver, and they offer free licenses to Open Source developers.

Answer (score 0):

"SQL Anywhere" from Sybase.